# Having problems creating a mechanic filter in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List<double> filtrar(List<double> lista, double Function(double) fn) {
  List<double> listaFiltrada = [];
  for (double elemento in lista) {
    if (fn(elemento) != null) {
      listaFiltrada.add(elemento);
    }
  }
  return listaFiltrada;
}

main() {
  var notas = [8.2, 7.3, 6.8, 5.4, 2.7, 9.3];
  var notasBoasFn = (nota) => nota >= 7.5;

  var somenteNotasBoas = filtrar(notas, notasBoasFn);
  print(somenteNotasBoas);
}
```

The main problem it's in the notasBoasFn, it's showing a red line saying that "The argument type 'dynamic Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double Function(double)"

I've tried to change the Function, making it return a bool, but the error continues.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `List<double> filtrar(List<double> lista, bool Function(double) fn) {
return lista.where(fn).toList();
}

main() {
var notas = [8.2, 7.3, 6.8, 5.4, 2.7, 9.3];
var notasBoasFn = (double nota) => nota >= 7.5;

var somenteNotasBoas = filtrar(notas, notasBoasFn);
print(somenteNotasBoas);`

Comment: and of course it can be even shorter: `main() {
var notas = [8.2, 7.3, 6.8, 5.4, 2.7, 9.3];
var notasBoasFn = (double nota) => nota >= 7.5;
var somenteNotasBoas1 = notas.where(notasBoasFn);
print(somenteNotasBoas1);
var somenteNotasBoas2 = notas.where((e) => e >= 7.5);
print(somenteNotasBoas2);
}`